# Symfony2 :: Add assets when a custom formtype is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I've created a service for loading a custom form-type.
But is it possible whenever I call this service, that automatically some javascript is autmaticlly loaded in mine block 'footer_javascripts' ? Because I don't want to load every time all the javascript.

At the moment, I'm doing it like this:

```
{% block wysiwyg_widget %}
    {% block footer_javascripts %}
       <script src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/js/demo/demo1.js') }}"></script>
       <script src="{{ asset('bundles/acme/js/demo/demo2.js') }}"></script>
   {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

But now the code is in the content, and I would like it in the block 'footer_javascript' and calling {{ parent() }} doesn't work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Loading all the Javascript is not a problem if the user visited another page (before viewing your page with the custom formtype) since the JS file will be cached.

Comment: Anyway, why do you use nested blocks? What are their roles?

Comment: Haaa okay, all the JS is cached? So it doesn't matter if I load it later or at the start. The nesteds block are just my temporary solution.

Comment: In theory yes the JS should be cached, the browser is not supposed to download the same files again and again.

Comment: Do you use a specific template for the custom form-type?

Comment: [Combining assets](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets) will result in less HTTP requests.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the solution. No, I'm using one template. Okay, I'll start using the combining assets. Thanks for your help

Comment: Another solution is to define a boolean in your controller (eg. `customFomType = (true|false)`) and add a test in your template to include the JS file only when needed.

Comment: Yeah, but then we need to add to all Controllers a boolean (and we have A LOT of controllers). So I was hoping I could fix it with blocks. But If all the JS is cached, than it isn't necessary that I only load the js-file when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can [combine your Javascript files](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#combining-assets) (and also CSS files) to reduce the number of HTTP requests.

You can use a variable to decide if the Javascript need to be loaded.

First, define it on your controller:

```php
public function homepageAction($no_locale = false)
{
    [...]

    $customFormType = null;

    if (/* test if you used the custom form-type */)
    {
            $customFormType = true;
    }

    return $this->render('SCACWebsiteBundle:Default:homepage.html.twig',
        array(
            'form' => $form,
            'customFormType ' => $customFormType
        )
    );
}
```

Then you can test the variable in Twig:

```twig
{% if ((customFormType is defined) and (customFormType)) %}
    {% javascripts
        'bundles/acme/js/demo/demo1.js'
        'bundles/acme/js/demo/demo2.js' %}
        <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endif %}
```

By using `(customFormType is defined)`, you don't need to declare the variable in all of your controller. This test ensures that there will be no error if the variable is not defined. The condition `(customFormType)` will be true only if the custom form-type will be loaded, even if it's the same controller, with or without the custom form-type. If the custom form-type is not loaded, `customFormType` will have the `null` value and the result of the condition will be false.